# Angular Build Process to hash the File Name of Asset and Resource Folders

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an **Angular 4.4.6** application and I build this using **Angular CLI 1.0.1**.

The problem I have is, apart from `inline.bundle.js`, `main.bundle`, `polyfills.bundle.js`, `styles.bundle.js`, `vendor.bundle.js` files names, all other File Names in "**assets**" and "**resources**" folder **are NOT hashed** when I build the application.

Since the file name is not hashed the request URLs for these files remain same and hence the browsers takes these files from cache it self and new changes are not reflecting.

Can somebody help how I can hash all the file names of "assets" and "resources" folders as well to avoid caching of these files ?

```
Build Command: ng build --prod --aot --no-sourcemap --output-hash=all
```

***OS***: Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: Try webpack, You'll end up being able to cache files on a more granular level, for one thing, and only redownload the files that have actually changed (instead of redownloading everything whenever the main chunk's hash changes).  https://codeburst.io/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95

Comment: Try this build command: ng build --prod --aot --sourcemap=false --output-hashing=all

Answer (score 1):

Simply set outputHashing to "all" in the `angular.json` file

```
"projects": {
   ...
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
           ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
             ...
              "outputHashing": "all",
...
```