# Angular: Add hashing to the files in assets during build

Tags: angular, typescript, hash, build, versioning

I have been looking up for the solution but nothing is useful is found yet.

**Problem:**
I have an application in angular and I've added custom styles and scripts in my assets folder. The location of my assets folder is **src->assets**. I make the build of my project using `ng build --prod --output-hashing=all` but the problem with this command is that it only hashes components & images used in my component but all the other files such as **CSS, js files, and images** that added by CSS are not hashed in the build.

It is causing problem on the customer side as due to continuous releases, sometimes the browser doesn't refresh CSS, JS files for new deployed release and they complain that the styling and features are not working.

**What I have tried:**
I tried many things like i mentioned above.

1. `ng build --prod`
2. `output-hashing`

But none of them have been beneficial for me. All i want is to get my custom css and js files get hashed during build. Is there any solution?

**PLEASE FEEL FREE TO ASK ANYTHING ELSE THAT IS REQUIRED OR I MISSED IN MY QUESTION**

***EDIT:** * Similar question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411349/angular-build-process-to-hash-the-file-name-of-asset-and-resource-folders) but not answered properly yet.

Comment: Ideally you should add your css to angular.json styles array and 3rd party js to the scripts array. If you do that, you will not have this issue.

Comment: @MikeOne yes i am aware of this. But for some reasons, we have to put them locally in assets/css folder

Comment: Well.. in that case you have 2 options I guess..1) use a custom webpack setup and do a post-rewrite with cachebuster string or 2) solve it serverside but setting up etags or caching headers with a cache cleaning mechanism. 

Both options kinda suck :-)

Comment: @MikeOne This is helpful. Thanks

Comment: I've got the same problem in an hybrid app, adding the template files to "assets" as their docs describe. I feel like this should have been thought through...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add `--output-hashing=all` flag to your build command when you want to build up the new bundles, just put this option in your angular.json file like the below:

```
    "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all", //Normally this is what you need
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
}
```

With this flag in your angular.json, normally all your CSS and js files will have a hash alongside the filename(something like main.64bc2a3e9a32c08c.js) so if the user simply opens the page it will be able to fetch the latest bundle. Btw --output-hashing has the below values:

```
none | all | media | bundles
```

So when you set it to all it means I want to add hash to all of the files.
Apart from that there is another option, you can take a look at cache busting concept in webpack

Answer (score -2):

Assets in the assets folder are not hashed only files in the root.

If you wish to hash files with --output-hashing=all, put them in the root as follows:

In angular.json in assest:[]

```
"assets": [
              "src/file.css",
              "src/file.js",
              "src/file.png",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "some/path",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],
```

file.css. file.js, file.png and all files from some/path will be copied to dist/yourProjectName and will be hashed with the hash of their content.
All files in assets will remain as is.

Comment: This does not work. The files added via "assets" don't get loaded through a Webpack loader, and don't get file hashing. There would be no way for any templates that reference these files to get altered filename.